# module 'connectivity' not found while creating archive for fastlane

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, cocoapods, fastlane

I am trying to deploy my ios app from fastlane. I have set up fastlane.  I got error while generating archive only. When i try to install app from xcode the app was installed successfully. I don't know what happen while generating archive.

```
[10:42:17]: ▸ Compiling GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m
[10:42:21]: ▸ ❌  /Users/flutter_app/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:12:9: module 'connectivity' not found
[10:42:21]: ▸ @import connectivity;
[10:42:21]: ▸  ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
[10:42:21]: ▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
```

I also try to create archive from terminal using Command

`xcodebuild -project Runner.xcodeproj -scheme Runner -archivePath runner.xcarchive archive`

but got same error as module 'connectivity' not found.

I have tried Some online solution like:

1. Delete pod files from project
   Delete podfile.lock from project
   run pod install
   deleted the repository and cloned again
2. Changing ios deployment target 12.1 in podfile & xcode
3. rm ios/Podfile && flutter build ios

But Nothing works for me.

Comment: given that connectivity is discontinued, you might want to check something like  https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus

Comment: I tried connectivity plus but got same error as ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:12:9: module 'connectivity_plus' not found @import connectivity_plus; 
 ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 ** ARCHIVE FAILED **